# Does the Polymer Starter Kit include a promise polyfill (for IE11)?

Tags: promise, internet-explorer-11, polyfills, polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit

If not, what is the best practice to use a promise polyfill with polymer ?
I am using Polymer 2
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue of compatibility with IE11 by adding this tag in the head section of the index file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Promise"></script>
```

Note that to have the app fully working with IE11 in dev mode (unbuilt), I have to use:

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Promise,fetch,Symbol,Array.prototype.@@iterator"></script>
```